# Rename file in Linux removing some strings

Tags: linux, rename

I have a lot of files with this format:

- download_agrupocqa_127_1656097965.tar.gz
- download_bjxkwris_127_1656097966.tar.gz
- download_climpieza_127_1656097965.tar.gz
- download_dhermagqu_127_1656097966.tar.gz

Do you know some command to rename all files in a folder to this format?

- agrupocqa.tar.gz
- bjxkwris.tar.gz
- climpieza.tar.gz
- dhermagqu.tar.gz

Which means remove: **download_** and **_127_1656097965**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH:

```bash
for file in *.tar.gz ; do 
    suffix="${file#download_}"      # this removes download_
    prefix="${suffix%%_*.tar.gz}"   # this removes everything after underscore
    mv "$file" "${prefix}.tar.gz"   # this renames the file
done
```

If you have `sed`:

```bash
for file in *.tar.gz ; do 
    newname=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/download_\([^_]*\)_[0-9_]*\..*/\1.tar.gz/')
    mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```